# React equivalent of document.createElement()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm currently using [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) in a React app. To create a custom marker you have to do something like this:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';

new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
.setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
.addTo(map);
```

It being React, I tried doing:

```
new mapboxgl.Marker(<div className='marker' />)
.setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
.addTo(map);
```

But that doesn't work... In the above context, what would be the equivalent of `document.createElement()`? When I use `document.createElement()` it works, but I feel that it's not the "correct" way to do things. I'd also like to abstract the marker into it's own component...

Comment: What happens if you try `mapboxgl.Marker(React.createElement('div', { className: 'marker' }, ''));`

Comment: @Dan This won't work because `React.createElement` creates ReactElement which is plain object, not a DOM Element.

Comment: It would be handy if there's a function that can take the object that `React.createElement` creates and parse it into a DOM element...

Comment: HI did you find how to do this in react. Or did you continue with `document.createElement`.?

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same problem and came up with two solutions:

### Solution 1

1.
Import ReactDOM library:

`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

2.
Create empty div as official Mapbox tutorial suggests:

```
const el = document.createElement("div");
el.className = "marker";
```

3.
Render your marker React component into newly created `el` element:

```
ReactDOM.render(<div className='marker' />, el);
```

4.
Add it to your map

```
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .addTo(map);
```

### Solution 2

1.
Import ReactDOMServer library:

`import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';`

2.
Create empty div as official Mapbox tutorial suggests:

```
const el = document.createElement("div");
el.className = "marker";
```

3.
Create static HTML markup out of your marker React component and assign it to `el.innerHTML`

```
el.innerHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<div className='marker' />);
```

4.
Add it to your map

```
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
  .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
  .addTo(map);
```

*Note* Solution 2 has one drawback. Marker element loses its interactivity and lifecycle methods (basically all benefits that we can get from React) since it becomes plain HTML markup.

Answer (score 6):

Part of React's secret sauce is you don't interact with the real DOM if you can help it, you make an update to virtual DOM if the state or props change and let React handle the rendering.

If you do need to do more traditional DOM manipulation, you would use refs (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to handle it in an isolated way. It's normally used sparingly, but seems to be perfect to use with Mapbox

My very naive example for this would be:

```
// Very simplified
class MapboxWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.markerRef = React.createRef();
  }

  createMarker() {
    new mapboxgl.Marker(this.markerRef)
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
      .addTo(map);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createMarker();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // ...Wrapper elements that you might need
      <div ref={this.markerRef} className="marker" />
    )  
  }
}
```

Courtesy of @jumoel, I would recommend reading the examples on https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-react-examples/tree/master/react-tooltip and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-react-examples/ more generally, as they are more fleshed out then this example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with React wrapper for Mapbox: [`react-mapbox-gl`](https://github.com/alex3165/react-mapbox-gl)

```
<Marker coordinates={coordinates} className={className}>
```

Comment: If you want to use vanilla Mapbox, you can look at their sample tooltip app using React: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-react-examples/tree/master/react-tooltip.

Comment: @jumoel I used those examples to flesh out my own answer, thanks!